# Is there a more efficient way to create this 2D list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I'm taking in a file with several lines of characters, like so:

```
oeoeoeo
eoeoeoe
oeoeoeo
eoeoeoe
oeoeoeo
```

I want to put them into a 2D list, like so:

```
[['o', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'o'],
 ['e', 'o', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'o', 'e'],
 ['o', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'o'],
 ['e', 'o', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'o', 'e'],
 ['o', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'o']]
```

This is how I'm currently accomplishing this:

```
map2dArray = []

for line in input_file:
    lineArray = []
    for character in line:
        lineArray.append(character)
    map2dArray.append(lineArray)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in a single line:

```
map(list, input_file)
```

or in Python 3:

```
list(map(list, input_file))
```

This generally leaves the newlines in the result, so if you want to get rid of those:

```
[list(line.strip('\n')) for line in input_file]
```